# How to add 2^63 to a signed 64-bit integer and cast it to a unsigned 64-bit integer without using 128-bit integer in the middle

Tags: c

I am writing a function that map signed integer space to unsigned integer space. But I want the negative number map before the positive number.

The method I am thinking of work like this
let say we have a signed 64-bit integer a.

1. Cast `a` to 128-bit
2. Add 2<sup>63</sup> to `a`
3. Cast it to unsigned 64-bit

However, the problem is, the C implementation I am working with does not have 128-bit integers.

Is there any efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arithmetic in unsigned types is modulo 2<sup>n</sup> (that is, it wraps around).

So all you need to do is:

1. Cast `a` to unsigned 64-bit
2. Add 2<sup>63</sup> to `a`

Comment: so you don't really need to cast a to unsigned explicitly. `a + (1ULL << 63)` will work

Comment: @AlvarMa `<<` is the left shift operator. It takes the number, in this case `1` of type `unsigned long long` and shift its bit to the left by `63`.  For example `1 << 1` is `2` (it would be `0...10` in bits), `1<< 3` is `8` because it is `0...001000` which is `8` in binary`. Basically `1 << n` is `2` to the power of `n`.

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc Bonus: `a + (1ULL << 63)` works even if `unsigned long long` is 128-bit.

Answer (score 2):

**just toggle MSB bit**:
1. cast `a` to unsigned 64-bit
2. xor with 2<sup>63</sup>  (or you may: add 2<sup>63</sup>).

which means you need to change (xor) just one bit (bit 63)
sample output:

```
a                    hex(a)              map(a)  
-9223372036854775808 0x8000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
-9223372036854775807 0x8000000000000001 0x0000000000000001
-9223372036854775806 0x8000000000000002 0x0000000000000002
-9223372036854775805 0x8000000000000003 0x0000000000000003
               -1000 0xfffffffffffffc18 0x7ffffffffffffc18
                 -10 0xfffffffffffffff6 0x7ffffffffffffff6
                  -1 0xffffffffffffffff 0x7fffffffffffffff
                   0 0x0000000000000000 0x8000000000000000
                   1 0x0000000000000001 0x8000000000000001
                  10 0x000000000000000a 0x800000000000000a
                 100 0x0000000000000064 0x8000000000000064
                1000 0x00000000000003e8 0x80000000000003e8
 9223372036854775805 0x7ffffffffffffffd 0xfffffffffffffffd
 9223372036854775806 0x7ffffffffffffffe 0xfffffffffffffffe
 9223372036854775807 0x7fffffffffffffff 0xffffffffffffffff
```

sample code (using add `// xor`):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
uint64_t show(int64_t n){
    uint64_t u = (uint64_t)n;
    u += (uint64_t)1 << 63;  // u ^= (uint64_t)1 << 63;
    printf("%21"PRId64" %21"PRIu64" 0x%016"PRIx64"\n", n, u, u); 
    return u;
}
int main()
{ 
    show(-1000);
    show(-10);
    show(-1);
    show(0);
    show(1);
    show(10);
    show(100);
    show(1000); 
    return 0;
}
```

**test sample code using union to demonstrate bit xor**(just  little-endian):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h> 

typedef union {
    uint8_t b[8];
    int64_t i;
    uint64_t u;
}T64bit;

uint64_t show(int64_t n){
    T64bit t;
    t.i = n;
    t.b[7] ^= 0x80;   // t.b[7] += 0x80;
    printf("%21"PRId64" %21"PRIu64" 0x%016"PRIx64"\n", n, t.u, t.u); 
    return t.u;
}
int main()
{
    show(-1000);
    show(-10);
    show(-1);
    show(0);
    show(1);
    show(10);
    show(100);
    show(1000);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
        -1000   9223372036854774808 0x7ffffffffffffc18
          -10   9223372036854775798 0x7ffffffffffffff6
           -1   9223372036854775807 0x7fffffffffffffff
            0   9223372036854775808 0x8000000000000000
            1   9223372036854775809 0x8000000000000001
           10   9223372036854775818 0x800000000000000a
          100   9223372036854775908 0x8000000000000064
         1000   9223372036854776808 0x80000000000003e8
```

Comment: Why are you obscuring the add by replacing it with xor??

Comment: This question is tagged `c`, not hardware implementation. There is no reason to believe that different code would be generated for `x^=1ULL<<63` vs `x+=1ULL<<63`, but writing xor when you mean plus obscures the meaning of the code gratuitously. Even in hardware modern HDLs do not encourage this kind of obfuscation but instead allow high-level transformations.

Comment: Why the cast in `u ^= (uint64_t)0x8000000000000000;`?  Better to use `PRIx64` than `"llx"`

Comment: Correct operation with `t.b[7] ^= 0x80;` is endian dependent.  C does not specify that the most-significant-byte is there.

Comment: @Amd: There is no such thing as "carry bit" in C. I don't "hate xor". I hate code that's written in a roundabout way that obscures the meaning because someone wrongly thought it would perform better (or even generate different machine code to begin with).